# Selection of active slick-slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code structure like this and i need to set some attributes for each first and last active element. How i can do that ?

```
<div class="slick-slider">
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active slick-current">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: `$('.slick-active:first')` & `$('.slick-active:last')`

Comment: in my case works only  $('.slick-active:first')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the `:first` and `:last` property selector for JQuery to get the first and last element of the desired class like shown below:

```js
var firstSlick = $('.slick-active:first');
var lastSlick = $('.slick-active:last');

$(firstSlick).addClass('first-slick');
$(lastSlick).addClass('last-slick');
```

```css
.first-slick{
  color:green;
}

.last-slick{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slick-slider">
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active slick-current">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide slick-active">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="slide-item slick-slide ">
        1
    </div>  
</div>
```

For better understanding i have added `first-slick` and `last-slick` classes to the first and last element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two way

**1.Jquery**

```
$('.slick-slider div.slide-item.slick-active:first') && $('.slick-slider div.slide-item.slick-active:last')
```

2.**CSS**

**div.slick-active:last-of-type**, **div.slick-active:first-of-type** 
{

}